# Store value in server - Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, server

So, I'm developing my first API using Spring Boot. This API calls and endpoint and uses a token to authenticate the requests made to it. I wanted to know if there is any way to store a variable in the server so I can access it for any request that is made to my API. The value that I want to store is a token provided by this endpoint, which is valid for a short period of time, and when it expires, I can make another request to get a new one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a DB/cache at your disposal to achieve this? Are you exclusively trying to find a solution to keep it in memory?

Comment: Will this be deployed in cloud/containers or traditional apache tomcat like servers?

Comment: No DB. I'm looking for something like a session variable that is shared between the users. Yes, this will be deployed on an apache tomcat server.

Comment: In general it is an anti-pattern to store state or use a session as you are describing when implementing a REST API.  If possible, I recommend making you API stateless from the start it makes it much easier to scale later.  I'd use a DB and lookup the token based on the users JWT token info, or whatever you are using.

Comment: The token that I want to save is only to make requests to the endpoint that I mentioned earlier. I need to make a call to update it every X hours. So is it okay to save it on a table, even if this table is going to have only 1 line? If that is not a problem, I'll do it

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JWT` authentication for securing your `API`.
See this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments, you might be better off using a cache(preferred) or DB. But if that's not possible, you can always use some in-memory solution which comes with its own perils like how to maintain state across different JVMs(in case there are multiple server)?

---

Now that we have that out of the way, let's see if you want to do this with an in-memory cache/database.

**Cache**
Explore in-memory cache implementation provided by [google guava library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) or something similar.
From the page-

> Generally, the Guava caching utilities are applicable whenever:
>
> - You are willing to spend some memory to improve speed.
> - You expect that keys will sometimes get queried more than once.
> - Your cache will not need to store more data than what would fit in RAM. (Guava caches are local to a single run of your application. They do not store data in files, or on outside servers. If this does not fit your needs, consider a tool like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).)

Load tokens during app bootstrap by implementing `CacheLoader` which will be invoked every time a new value is needed.

```
LoadingCache<String, String> tokensByResource = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
         public Token load(String resource) throws AnyException {
           return createToken(key);
         }
       });
```

Retrieve cache token before each REST invocation-

```
try {
  return tokensByResource.get(key);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
}
```

**Database**

Consider using an in-memory/embedded database which Spring Boot supports [like H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html). If you don't want to loose data with server restart, a file location can be provided(more on this below). [H2 also comes with a console](https://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html#h2_console) which can be useful in debugging/reporting etc.

Add maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this to applicaton.properties-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

#Use following to preserve data to file between restarts
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/demo
```

Once you have this setup, treat it like any other plain-old SQL database for CRUD operations. During app initialization, bootstrap token generation and save it to `H2`.